# put two SKSpriteNodes as childs to a SKNodes

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

I am trying to group two SKSpriteNodes into a SKNode but I do not get my head around in properly.

Right below my class declaration I declare my SpriteNode and Node

```
var waterGroup: SKNode!
var water1: SKSpriteNode!
var water2: SKSpriteNode!
```

Then I add some 'life' to the water SKSpriteNodes with

```
water1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "water_1")
addChild(water1)
water2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "water_2")
addChild(water2)
```

But then I am stuck and do not know how to add water1 and water2 as childs to waterGroup.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

addChild over the group like this:

```
var waterGroup: SKNode! = SKNode()
var water1: SKSpriteNode!
var water2: SKSpriteNode!

water1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "water_1")
waterGroup.addChild(water1)
water2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "water_2")
waterGroup.addChild(water2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I do so like you mentioned, I always get a 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional' error from the compiler. Can you explain how come?

Comment: @boehmatron Probably do you need initialize waterGroup first, like var waterGroup: SKNode! = SKNode(). I edit my answer :)